# monkeypatch a function that needs to be imported in conftest

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm trying to use `pytest.monkeypatch` to patch a function I've defined in another file. I then need to patch a function from another that relies on this first `monkeypatch`. Here's a simple example

```
# class_def.py
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        # Normally, there is something that makes self.p
        # that will use a file that will exist on production
        raise FileNotFoundError

def factory():
    print('in factory')
    return C()

----
# function_def.py
from .class_def import factory

foo = factory()

def bar():
    return 0

----
# conftest.py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import pytest

import playground.class_def

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_c(monkeypatch):
    fake_c = MagicMock()
    def factory():
        print('in monkey factory')
        return fake_c
    monkeypatch.setattr('playground.class_def.factory', factory)

from .function_def import bar

# Then I would patch bar
```

And running `pytest .` will fail with `FileNotFoundError`. I believe this happens because I am calling `foo = factory()` at the top level of `function_def.py`. I expected this not to happen because I am patching `factory` before doing this import, but that doesn't seem to be happening. Is there a way to ensure this `monkeypatch.setattr` will go into effect before `from .function_def import bar` in `conftest.py`?

Also, the file structure looks like

```
playground
|--- __init__.py
|--- conftest.py
|--- class_def.py
|--- function_def
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have direct access to the attribute you want to change. You don't need monkeypatch at all.

Here's my tree :

```
$ tree .
.
├── a.py
├── b.py
├── __init__.py
└── test_a.py

0 directories, 4 files
```

a.py

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        raise Exception

def factory():
    return A()
```

b.py

```
import a

print(a.factory())
```

test_a.py

```
import a


def test_a():
    def fake_factory():
        return 'A'
    a.factory = fake_factory
    import b
```

And it works:

```
$ pytest
=============================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.5.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/ahorgnies/test/monkeypatch, inifile:
plugins: remotedata-0.2.1, openfiles-0.3.0, doctestplus-0.1.3, arraydiff-0.2
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                  

test_a.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                 [100%]

============================================================================================ 1 passed in 0.01 seconds =============================================================================================
```

Comment: I am importing it before patching. My order of operations in `conftest.py` is 1. `import playground.class_def` 2. monkeypatch `playground.class_def.factory` so it won't throw an error. 3. `from .function_def import bar` which calls `playground.class_def.factory()` at the top-level. The problem that I'm seeing is that that `monkeypatch` in step 2 isn't going in effect before step 3.

Comment: You cannot patch something before it exists.

Comment: Anyway, your case can be solved by directly modifying the attribute. Here you go. I adapted my answer.